# Evaluating more than one open notebook in Mathematica without mixing issues

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

I have two open Mathematica notebook files, call them file A and file B, that are identical except for some initial parameter conditions that I manually input at the beginning of each file (all the remaining code and variable names are the same). The two files are supposed to be be independent and both perform the same calculation subject to the given initial conditions. If I now ask Mathematica to run file A and, while it is still working on it, I go to file B and ask Mathematica to run it also, will they eventually run in the correct order I intended (second file runs only after the first one finishes, without any mixing of command sequences or contents)?  In other words, will the two files not be influenced by each other's contents and will Mathematica follow exactly the same sequence in which I asked for the files (or cells) to be run?

Comment: They will interfere unless you specify a different kernel for each notebook in the `Evaluation` menu.

Comment: You could also clear the variable definitions at the beginning of each notebook if you intend to use this workflow.

Comment: With separate kernels you can execute both notebooks simultaneously without interference from the other.

Comment: Take a look at `Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context` in menu - you can set a notebook to have a unique context, may be useful for your needs.

Comment: If your license allows for it, I would suggest you start two instances of Mathematicibstead of opening both notebooks from the same one. This gives you two completely separate front-ends and kernels, and you can then easily run both notebooks at the same time with no interference between them.

Comment: @catrevillian so, if clearing or reassigning the variables at the beginning of second file would work, wouldn't that imply that Mathematica had indeed finished the first file first, in the intended sequence, before beginning the second file?

Comment: user135626, if you are running them on the same kernel, then yes, the second notebook would not run until the first notebook completed evaluation in the kernel. However, if you only clear variables initially in the second notebook, and switch back to run the first notebook, then you would run into the conflicting definitions issues you want to avoid, assuming that you continue to run these in the same kernel. This is why I suggested to clear variables at the beginning of each notebook. Use of multiple kernels would mean that definitions do not conflict & you can run notebooks simultaneously.

Comment: @catrevillian thanks for this! The default setting of Global notebook context was chosen. I guess this means that they shared kernels, right? But at the beginning of each file I reassign the key variables, so I guess this should be acceptable as long as I run each file including these initial lines. I was fearing that Mathematica might decide to jump from a cell in one file to another cell in the second file without going in the right order (finish one file completely, then move to next file).